# Site is redirecting from http:// to http://http// (no colon)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, redirect, cpanel

We are transferring servers tonight, and we started the process. The new DNS has resolved and everything, but if you type in the site name [localreviewengine.com](http://localreviewengine.com). It kicks it to `http//localreviewengine.com` (so really, `http://http//localreviewengine.com`).

What would cause that? It's a wordpress install, and Sitename and Home in the DB are set properly, there are no redirects in CPanel, and the htaccess looks fine?

**EDIT**: It looks like [localreviewengine.com/readme.html](http://localreviewengine.com/readme.html) works though..?

Answer (score 1):

Watching the response headers for this site brings a bit light into the dark:

```
~ # curl -I "http://localreviewengine.com/"
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sat, 01 Dec 2012 01:57:11 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips DAV/2 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Location: http://http://localreviewengine.com
Content-Type: text/html
```

As you can see webserver is redirecting to `http://http://localreviewengine.com`
That's a typo / incorrect protocol prefix in your configuration.

check your apache config or (most likely) your document root `.htaccess`

Did you add any redirect / rewrites for the move process? e.g. `we're moving our site, come back when the 5.000 machines are finally up and running again? (hopefully)`

Comment: new server and php is already outdated tss tss, this server admin folks :)

Comment: did you solve the issue? post your configuration or eventual htaccess files if you still need help